# Can I turn a .TXT file into a ZipInfo file/item/format, in order to add it to archive.infolist()?

Tags: python, zip, txt

So I am doing some processing with a few `.TXT` files and one `.ZIP` file:

```
    for file in input_files:

        with archive_class(str(compressed_file), 'r') as archive:
            for file in archive.infolist():
            ....
```

So within `input_files` I have a few `.TXT` files and one `.ZIP` file.

Note that `archive.infolist()` is a list of ZipInfo's that look like this:

```
[<ZipInfo filename='MC_TICK_AE_20230703.TXT' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20 file_size=15770 compress_size=2683>, <ZipInfo filename='MC_TICK_A_20230703.TXT' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20 file_size=23480527 compress_size=2531906>]
```

And I need to add my `.TXT` files to this list. Is this possible? In my mind I would need to turn my `.TXT` files into a `ZipInfo` format? Then add it to the list? I could be completely off here.

Comment: No, you don't need to add your own txt as ZipInfo. What you need is to add your txt to the zip and the .infolist will list it then. See ZipFile.write - https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll give it a try, no idea why it didn't hit me to just add it to the zip...